# Can't shut down/restart/suspend from the GUI

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, shutdown

So I'm running xUbuntu (16.10) on my laptop for some time now (3 months more or less) an I hadn't ran into any problem I couldn't solve with a simple google search. This was until I encountered the before-mentioned problem (title).

The problem is essentially what I've written in the title. I go to shut down/suspend/reboot my pc from the GUI and instead of that occurring it just logs me out of my session. From the login screen I still can't shut down or suspend, having to resort to manually using the shut down button on the machine. When I try to run the shutdown command from the terminal (or the reboot one) it always tells me there's already a shutdown command in place (it's like something is creating a shutdown proccess 90sec in the future).

Does someone have a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Do you have my-weather-indicator installed?

Comment: ps: When the shutdown hangs, you might be able to hit the ESC key and a textual screen should appear, and then you can see what the last event was, and help determine why the problem exists.

Comment: No i do not have that indicator installed. Will check on the last event that's preventing the shutdown